# Text wrapping images in posts

Tags: feature-request, design, images, editor

The space at right side is blank. In text mode editing with MS docx for example, we can fill up space with text.

[image: Unit_Circles_BeltramiPS]When a small image is attached for questions or answers some white space at the sides is wasted. If a tight wrap edit can place image alongside text it becomes more readable. Is it possible to include this feature?

Comment: An example would make this a ton more understandable..